# window.open in https iframe does not open as pop up

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, microsoft-edge

I have a very simple button that opens a login popup window.  The button is placed inside an iframe.  The button resides on a different web site than the main page.  When running this on my dev/stage site, all using http, all works as expected, the login pops up with no menubar or extra stuff.  As soon as I copy to production and try and load the iframe content over https (main page still http) then Microsoft Edge ignores my settings to not show menubar, etc. and opens the button in a normal browser window, in another session.  This works fine in IE, Chrome, etc.  I cannot find anything published that says Edge is doing something different for cross browser and https iframed inside an http page.

Here is the resulting html for the iframe and it's contents:

```
<iframe name="logInOut_btn_iframe" width="200" height="32" class="btn-login-iFrame" id="logInOut_btn_iframe" src="https://www.website.org/logInOut_btn_iFramed.html" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="yes">

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html lang="en" lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
        <title>State Bar of Arizona :: Login Status</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON">

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function loginPop() {
                var loginWin = window.open("/loginPop.cfm" + decodeURIComponent( document.location.hash ), "SBA_Login" + Math.random(), config= "width=500,height=315,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,resizable=yes,top=" + ((screen.availHeight/2)-150) + ",left=" + ((screen.availWidth/2)-250));
                loginWin.opener = self;
                loginWin.focus();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:loginPop();">Member Login</a>
    </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Not an expert but `iframe` is deprecated.

Comment: Yes but iframe is a necessity when you still have to support older systems.

Comment: And actually still supported, per the MS Edge web site:  https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/apireference/htmlelements/iframe/

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko Can you link to a live resource that shows the issue?

Comment: @iharob The [`iframe` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) *is not* deprecated. You may be thinking of [`frameset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#frames).

Comment: Go here and click the Member Login button.  Works fine for several years until Edge seems to have broken it:  http://www.azbar.org/Lawyers

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I work on the Edge team, and will definitely look into the issue. My apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I just tested the site from Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0 and the popup appeared without any issue. Which version of Edge are you testing with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99759/discussion-between-sampson-and-connie-decinko).